# Regex/bash find string with most recent date?

Tags: regex, bash, date

For my personal backup scheme, I have a set of folders whose names are in the pattern `(something)_(day)(month)(year)_T(hour)(minute)(second)`. Here's a sample:

```
01.hourly_02102016_T171011
00.daily_27092016_T102203
00.weekly_17032015_T050600
```

I want to select from this list the folder with the most recent time in its name. How would I do that in a bash script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps, the shortest command:

```
ls -1 | sort -t_ -k2.5nr,2 -k2.3nr,2 -k2.1nr,2 -k3r
```

It sorts by years, months, and days, in that order. The `-t` option specifies field separator for the column numbers used in `-k` option values.

The `-kX.Ynr,2` options stand for sorting by column `X`, character number `Y` in reverse (`r`) numeric order (`n`); stop sorting at column 2 (the last character after comma).

```
          -k2.5
··············v
00.weekly_17032015_T050600
          ^^^^^^^^
          column 2
```

The last `-k3r` sorts by the third column in reverse order.

The most recent will be at the top of the list. You can select it by appending `| head -1` to the end of the command.

Comment: Nice... add ` -k3r` at the end to also sort by time ;-)

Answer (score 2):

*Assuming that all the files in the directory are in the pattern that you described,* then you can sort the names by rearranging `(day)(month)(year)` as `(year)(month)(day)`:

```
ls | sed -e 's/.*_\(..\)\(..\)\(....\)_\(T.*\)/& \3\2\1\4/' | \
    sort -rk2 | awk '{ print $1; exit }'
```

Explanation:

- The `sed` captures the `(day)(month)(year)(_Ttime)` and appends at the end of the line rearranged as `(year)(month)(day)(_Ttime)`
- We sort by the second field with `-k2`, the rearranged value we added at the end of each line with `sed`, and use reverse order with `-r` to get the latest value at the top
- The `awk` prints the first field and exits

If filenames may contain spaces, you can use a different field separator as appropriate.

Btw, all this would have been a lot easier if you used a different naming scheme for the backup files. Had you used `(year)(month)(day)` in the first place, you could get the latest item much simpler with:

```
ls | sort -rt_ -k2 | head -n 1
```

Comment: [Don't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: If I understand it correctly, you sort by date, but not by time. Right?

Comment: Good point @chepner, I added an assumption to make this acceptable to do.